# Выравнивание кнопок

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Нужно сделать кнопки на одном уровне, точнее, поместить их как-то вниз блока.
Пытался это сделать свойством `align-items: flex-end`(оно закомментированно), ничего не произошло.
[image: 1]

```css
body {
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
 margin-left: 50px;
 max-width: 1185px;
 margin-right: 50px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.h {
font-size: 30px;
color: #445161;
}

.bg {
 background-color: #445162;
 max-width: 300px;
}

.vertical-columns {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 padding-top: 35px;
 
}

.vertical-align h2 {
 text-align: center;
}

.vertical-align {
 margin-top: 95px;
}

.vertical-columns h3 {
 font-size: 24px;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 18px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.vertical-columns h4 {
 font-size: 40px;
 text-transform: lowercase;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 25px 25px;
 border: 2px solid #445162;
 background-color: #fff;
 color: #445162;
 margin-top: 14px;
}

.vertical-columns p {
 color: #fff;
 padding: 21px;
 line-height: 1.5;
}

.bg a {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 /*align-items: flex-end;*/
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #445162;
 padding: 15px 70px;
 background-color: #fff;
 margin: 0 20px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="container vertical-align">
  <h2 class="h">Вертикальное выравнивание</h2>
  <div class="vertical-columns">
   <div class="first-column bg">
    <h3>Буду рад</h3>
    <h4>Подписке</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint tenetur fugit vel, eligendi illum, placeat quo vero reiciendis consectetur.</p>
    <a>Подписаться</a>
   </div>
   <div class="second-column bg">
    <h3>Буду рад</h3>
    <h4>Лайку</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint tenetur fugit vel, eligendi illum, placeat quo vero reiciendis consectetur.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint tenetur fugit vel, eligendi illum, placeat quo vero reiciendis consectetur tempora voluptatum dolorum.</p>
    <a>Лайк</a>
   </div>
   <div class="third-column bg">
    <h3>Буду рад</h3>
    <h4>Комментарию</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint tenetur fugit vel, eligendi illum, placeat quo vero reiciendis consectetur.</p>
    <a href="#">Комментировать</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не вмешиваемся в разметку, оперируем только стилями (*добавленные свойства и комментарии в коде CSS*) :

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  margin-left: 50px;
  max-width: 1185px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.h {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #445161;
}

.bg {
  background-color: #445162;
  max-width: 300px;
  /* Флексим колонки без переносов */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.vertical-columns {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 35px;
}

.vertical-align h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.vertical-align {
  margin-top: 95px;
}

.vertical-columns h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.vertical-columns h4 {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 25px;
  border: 2px solid #445162;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #445162;
  margin-top: 14px;
}

.vertical-columns p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 21px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  /* Отдаём всё пространство, что можем, 
  параграфам и они прижмут кнопки */
  flex: 1;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
}

.bg a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /*align-items: flex-end;*/
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #445162;
  padding: 15px 70px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="container vertical-align">
  <h2 class="h">Вертикальное выравнивание</h2>
  <div class="vertical-columns">
    <div class="first-column bg">
      <h3>Буду рад</h3>
      <h4>Подписке</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint tenetur fugit vel, eligendi illum, placeat quo vero reiciendis consectetur.</p>
      <a>Подписаться</a>
    </div>
    <div class="second-column bg">
      <h3>Буду рад</h3>
      <h4>Лайку</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint tenetur fugit vel, eligendi illum, placeat quo vero reiciendis consectetur.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint tenetur fugit vel, eligendi illum, placeat quo vero reiciendis consectetur tempora voluptatum dolorum.</p>
      <a>Лайк</a>
    </div>
    <div class="third-column bg">
      <h3>Буду рад</h3>
      <h4>Комментарию</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint tenetur fugit vel, eligendi illum, placeat quo vero reiciendis consectetur.</p>
      <a href="#">Комментировать</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое решение(наверное):

```
<section class="container vertical-align">
    <h2 class="h">Вертикальное выравнивание</h2>
    <div class="vertical-columns">
        <div class="first-column bg">
    <div class="cl">
      <h3>Буду рад</h3>
            <h4>Подписке</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint tenetur fugit vel, eligendi illum, placeat quo vero reiciendis consectetur.</p>
    </div>
            <a>Подписаться</a>
        </div>
        <div class="second-column bg">
    <div class="cl">
      <h3>Буду рад</h3>
            <h4>Лайку</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint tenetur fugit vel, eligendi illum, placeat quo vero reiciendis consectetur.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint tenetur fugit vel, eligendi illum, placeat quo vero reiciendis consectetur tempora voluptatum dolorum.</p>
    </div>
            <a>Лайк</a>
        </div>
        <div class="third-column bg">
    <div class="cl">
      <h3>Буду рад</h3>
      <h4>Комментарию</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint tenetur fugit vel, eligendi illum, placeat quo vero reiciendis consectetur.</p>
    </div>

            <a href="#">Комментировать</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

body {


font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
    margin-left: 50px;
    max-width: 1185px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.h {
font-size: 30px;
color: #445161;
}

.bg {
    background-color: #445162;
    max-width: 300px;
}

.vertical-columns {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 35px;

}

.vertical-align h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

.vertical-align {
    margin-top: 95px;
}

.vertical-columns h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.vertical-columns h4 {
    font-size: 40px;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px 25px;
    border: 2px solid #445162;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #445162;
    margin-top: 14px;
}

.vertical-columns p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 21px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
.cl{
  height:90%;
}
.bg a {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    /*align-items: flex-end;*/
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #445162;
    padding: 15px 70px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```